# type list box with increase /create buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i want to make list box as shown picture to increase /decrease this box value. how to get this type of text box using jqueryui or css .please suggest ,

[image]

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  I can do your homework assignment for you, but that probably won't help you learn.

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ckj9/1/)**

Try this..

```
Xpos<input type="number" style='width:60px' value='66'></input>
Ypos<input type="number" style='width:60px' value='83'></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like a [html5 number field](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) than a list

```
<input type="number" value="0"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vSz4a/)

*Note: < IE10 does not support type="Number"*

Answer (score 0):

by number property its working but only that browser in which html 5 support

so it is better to use a way by which it is show in every browser

so use  [jquery ui spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#decimal)

[jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/)  support in all browser